# Any Way to Filter Without Renaming Columns

Tags: python, pandas, filter

I have two lines of code like this:

```
df.rename(columns={'Name': 'q1', 'Age': 'q2', 'Weight': 'q3', 'Height': 'q4', 'DOB': 'q5', 'Donor': 'q6'},  inplace = True)
df = (df.filter(like = 'q').groupby([df['Name'], df['Type'],df['DATE']]).agg(lambda x: x.eq(4).sum()/x.count()))
```

I want to filter by specific columns and then perform groupby but currently, in order to do this, I am renaming each of the columns to q1 - q6 and then filtering if 'q' is what the column starts with.

Can I do this without renaming column names to q?

Comment: [use indexing.](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html)
It seems that filtering df is not necessary. It should be enough to specify multiple columns to apply `agg` with `[ ] indexing`. [If you provide an example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), I can provide detailed code.

Comment: If you're renaming all to `qX` and then filtering everything that start with `q`, how is this filtering anything?

Comment: I want to filter specifically for those six columns so I renamed them each to q1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 and then performed the groupby. But this seems tedious.

Comment: Does this code run without errors on your machine? I ask because in the first line of code you rename column 'Name' to 'q1', but then in the second line of code you select column 'Name' (which by then should not exist anymore).

Answer (score 4):

Just select the columns, optionally renaming programmatically (only if needed) **after** aggregation:

```
cols = ['Name', 'Age', 'Weight', 'Height', 'DOB', 'Donor']
out_cols = [f'q{x+1}' for x in range(len(cols))]

out = (df[cols]
       .groupby([df['Name'], df['Type'],df['DATE']], as_index=False)
       .agg(lambda x: x.eq(4).sum()/x.count())
       .set_axis(out_cols, axis=1) # optional
      )
```

Or renaming during aggregation:

```
cols = ['Name', 'Age', 'Weight', 'Height', 'DOB', 'Donor']

out = (df
       .groupby([df['Name'], df['Type'],df['DATE']])
       .agg(**{f'q{x}': (c, lambda x: x.eq(4).sum()/x.count())
               for x,c in enumerate(cols)})
      )
```

Example outputs:

```
# first approach with renaming
  q1   q2   q3   q4   q5   q6
0  A  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
1  A  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
2  A  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
3  A  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
4  B  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
5  B  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
6  B  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
7  C  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
8  C  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
9  C  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0

# first approach without renaming
  Name  Age  Weight  Height  DOB  Donor
0    A  0.0     0.0     0.0  0.0    0.0
1    A  0.0     0.0     0.0  0.0    0.0
2    A  0.0     0.0     0.0  0.0    0.0
3    A  0.0     0.0     0.0  0.0    0.0
4    B  0.0     0.0     0.0  0.0    0.0
5    B  0.0     0.0     0.0  0.0    0.0
6    B  0.0     0.0     0.0  0.0    0.0
7    C  0.0     0.0     0.0  0.0    0.0
8    C  0.0     0.0     0.0  0.0    0.0
9    C  0.0     0.0     0.0  0.0    0.0


# second approach
                       q0   q1   q2   q3   q4   q5
Name Type DATE                                    
A    A    2023-10-10  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
          2023-10-12  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
     B    2023-10-11  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
          2023-10-13  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
B    A    2023-10-11  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
     B    2023-10-10  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
          2023-10-12  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
C    A    2023-10-11  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
          2023-10-13  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
     B    2023-10-12  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
```