# Pyspark - JSON string column explode into multiple without mentioning schema

Tags: json, pyspark, schema

I have below JSON string as a column in a pyspark dataframe.

```
{
   "result":{
      "version":"1.2",
      "timeStamp":"2023-08-14 14:00:12",
      "description":"",
      "data":{
         "DateTime_Received":"2023-08-14T14:01:10.4516457+01:00",
         "DateTime_Actual":"2023-08-14T14:00:12",
         "OtherInfo":null,
         "main":[
            {
               "Status":0,
               "ID":111,
               "details":null
            }
         ]
      },
      "tn":"aaa"
   }
}
```

I want to explode the above one into multiple columns without hardcoding the schema.

I tried using schema_of_json to generate schema from the json string.

```
df_decoded = df_decoded.withColumn("json_column", F.when(F.col("value").isNotNull(), F.col("value")).otherwise("{}"))

# Infer the schema using schema_of_json
json_schema = df_decoded.select(F.schema_of_json(F.col("json_column"))).collect()[0][0]
```

df_decoded is my dataframe and value is my json string column name.

But it is giving me the below error -

```
AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'schema_of_json(json_column)' due to data type mismatch: The input json should be a foldable string expression and not null; however, got json_column.;
```

My expected output -
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Does this start you on the way ?

```
import json
import pandas as pd

j = '''{
   "result":{
      "version":"1.2",
      "timeStamp":"2023-08-14 14:00:12",
      "description":"",
      "data":{
         "DateTime_Received":"2023-08-14T14:01:10.4516457+01:00",
         "DateTime_Actual":"2023-08-14T14:00:12",
         "OtherInfo":null,
         "main":[
            {
               "Status":0,
               "ID":111,
               "details":null
            }
         ]
      },
      "tn":"aaa"
   }
}'''


text_json = json.loads(j)
result=text_json.get("result", "")
print(result.get("version", ""))

results = [result["version"], result["timeStamp"], result["description"], result["data"], result["tn"] ]
df = pd.DataFrame(results).transpose()
print(df)
```

I don't have a real app to play with
`.transpose()` is the change.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/77263073/22187484
This person has a complex answer for grouping and filtering that might help too.

Answer (score 0):

Use sparks inference engine to get the schema of json column then cast the json column to struct then use select expression to explode the struct fields as columns

```
schema = spark.read.json(df.rdd.map(lambda r: r['value'])).schema
result = df.withColumn('value', F.from_json('value', schema)).select('*', 'value.result.*')
```

---

```
+--------------------+--------------------+-----------+-------------------+---+-------+
|               value|                data|description|          timeStamp| tn|version|
+--------------------+--------------------+-----------+-------------------+---+-------+
|{{{2023-08-14T14:...|{2023-08-14T14:00...|           |2023-08-14 14:00:12|aaa|    1.2|
+--------------------+--------------------+-----------+-------------------+---+-------+
```